# scrollWidth not detecting overflow

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

How do I accurately detect overflow in Javascript when scrollWidth is of no help?

My goal is to display the largest text possible in a div without exceeding the div boundaries (i.e. no overflow).  The text in question could be a single letter, or it could be a long paragraph.

I'm having issues where part of the lowercase "f" (non-fixed-width-font) does overflow visibly and yet scrollWidth indicates no overflow has occurred (i.e. element.scrollWidth == element.offsetWidth).

I’m aware this will not be an issue with fixed-width fonts so please avoid suggesting them.

The code snippet illustrates overflow (at least visually), yet scrollWidth hasn't exceeded the div width.  I've reproduced the same results (last "f" exceeds boundaries) in Windows 7 (Chrome Version 54, FireFox 50.0, IE 11), Kindle Fire (Silk), iPad (iOS 9.3.5 Safari) and Android 5.1.0 (Chrome 54.0).

After much research, I’ve ruled out ligature settings, letter-spacing and appending a zero-width non-joiner (ZWNJ) as none of them appears useful to trigger, or avoid, overflow in this case.  I’ve read through each StackExchange post relating to [javascript] "offsetWidth" "scrollWidth" "overflow".  I’ve even gone as far as checking out font structure from http://opentype.js.org where the lowercase “f” exceeds the “Draw Metrics” which may give hints to the solution, but is beyond my comprehension at this point.

```js
window.onload = main;

function GrowToFit(obj) {
  if (obj.offsetWidth == obj.scrollWidth) {
    //No overlap, grow font by 1 px
    obj.style.fontSize = ++x + "px";
    //Repeat
    GrowToFit(obj);
  } else {
    //back off 1 font size so no overlap
    obj.style.fontSize = --x + "px";
  }
}

function main() {
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    x = 1;
    obj = document.getElementById("Box" + i);
    GrowToFit(obj);
    Results.innerHTML += "Box" + i + "<br />Font Size=" + obj.style.fontSize;
    Results.innerHTML += "<br />scrollWidth=" + obj.scrollWidth;
    Results.innerHTML += "<br />offsetWidth=" + obj.offsetWidth + "<br /><br />";
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  /* For contrast */
  font-size: 1px;
  /*Will upsize in GrowToFit*/
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="Box1" class="box">fff</div>
<!-- last f will hang outside div -->
<br />
<div id="Box2" class="box">xxx</div>
<!-- fits no problem -->
<br />
<div id="Box3" class="box">FFF</div>
<!-- fits no problem -->
<br />
<div id="Results"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, try using jQuery. Include it and use its innerWidth() function to detect the overflow

Comment: I ran two separate tests with margin, padding and border all set to zero for the div.  The first test had the text fully contained within the div.  For the second test, the text blew way past the boundaries of the div.  jQuery's innerWidth value was the same as JavaScript's offsetWidth for both tests.  No overflow was revealed using JQuery innerWidth.